# Code coverage gets generated only for Tests project

Tags: .net, .net-core, code-coverage, mstest, coverlet

I've got a project (say `A.csproj`) and a tests project (say `T.csproj`).

T has `coverlet.msbuild` and `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` as nuget references. T has a `.runsettings` file with no include include/exclude paths (all assemblies included, non excluded).

Doing `dotnet test T.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:IncludeTestAssembly=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura --settings:".runsettings"`, results in only coverage being generated for the tests project:

```
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Module             | Line   | Branch | Method |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| T                  | 98.87% | 100%   | 96.29% |
+--------------------+--------+--------+--------+

+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|         | Line   | Branch | Method |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Total   | 98.87% | 100%   | 96.29% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Average | 98.87% | 100%   | 96.29% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
```

If I drop  `/p:IncludeTestAssembly=true`, there's only an empty report generated:

```
| Module | Line | Branch | Method |
+--------+------+--------+--------+

+---------+------+--------+--------+
|         | Line | Branch | Method |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| Total   | 0%   | 0%     | 0%     |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
| Average | 0%   | 0%     | 0%     |
+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

The same happens even when I specify for inclusion for all modules via the cmdline itself: `dotnet test T.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:Include="[*]*"`

Contents of `T.csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>-->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>false</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>false</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="3.1.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="4.18.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\E2EPoC.Specs\E2EPoC.Specs.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: is it possible to put content of `T.csproj`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$>src> dotnet test <YOUR_PROJECT>.sln --no-build /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutput=..\results\coverage /p:MergeWith=..\results\coverage.json /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
```

```
$>src> reportgenerator -reports:**/coverage.opencover.xml -targetdir:Tests\results\WebResult
```

```
$>src> Tests\results\WebResult\index.html
```